# Did my rsync successfully back-up all data or not?

Tags: rsync

It looks like not a single byte is missing after the rsync, but there were some errors:

```
ujjain@DS3018xs:/volume1$ cat rsync.sh
rsync -av photo.tar /var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/
rsync -av music.tar /var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/
ujjain@nas:/volume2/Files/RAIDF1$ ls -al
total 418910340
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 admin        users           36 Nov 29 22:54 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 ujjain users          410 Nov 29 21:47 ..
-rw-------  1 admin        users  53127639040 Nov 29 20:52 music.tar
-rw-------  1 admin        users 375836549120 Nov 29 20:50 photo.tar
ujjain@nas:/volume2/Files/RAIDF1$
root@DS3018xs:/volume1# ls -al *tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ujjain root  53127639040 Nov 29 20:52 music.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ujjain root 375836549120 Nov 29 20:50 photo.tar
root@DS3018xs:/volume1# cat nohup.out
sending incremental file list
created directory /var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1
photo.tar
rsync: chown "/var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/.photo.tar.qeeaLI" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 375882427699 bytes  received 31 bytes  107165339.34 bytes/sec
total size is 375836549120  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1355) [sender=3.0.9]
sending incremental file list
music.tar
rsync: chown "/var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/.music.tar.mHlkfL" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 53134124438 bytes  received 31 bytes  105739551.18 bytes/sec
total size is 53127639040  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1355) [sender=3.0.9]
root@DS3018xs:/volume1#
```

Did my rsync succesfully back-up all data or not?

Comment: You could try to do a restore? People ask for those more than backups :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rsync is failing to set attributes on the destination (chown failure).  Perhaps the filesystem doesn't support it?

The `-a` flag sets many options, including  `-o`, which will attempt to set the owner of the destination file when the destination is running as root.  If you don't need the owner set, then you can tell rsync to not bother by adding the `--no-owner` flag (or by removing `-a`, but you probably don't want to do that).

The data in the file was probably copied just fine.  It's only the metadata about the file (ownership) that shows an error.